# Spring, Hibernate, Many-To-Many - Лишние селекты во время обновления сущности

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Друзья, нужна помощь!

Есть две сущности связанные отношением многие-ко-многим:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Student> students;

    public Group(String name, List<Student> students) {
        this.name = name;
        this.students = students;
    }

   // skipped
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // skipped
}
```

И примерно такой код, который делает **update** сущности `Group`:

```java
public Optional<Group> updateGroup(Long id, String name, Collection<Long> studentIds) {   
    return groupRepo.findById(id)
        .map(group -> {

            boolean isChanged = false;

            if (name != null) {
                group.setName(name);
                isChanged = true;
            }

            if (studentIds != null && !studentIds.isEmpty()) {
                List<Student> students = toRefList(studentIds, studentRepo);
                group.setStudents(students);
                isChanged = true;
            }

            if (isChanged) {
                return groupRepo.save(group);
            } else {
                return group;
            }
        });
}

private <T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> List<T> toRefList(Collection<ID> ids, JpaRepository<T, ID> repo) {
    return ids.stream()
        .map(repo::getOne) // take reference to the entity
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Метод `updateGroup` получает на вход, кроме прочего, список ID-шников связнных сущностией (`Student` в данном случае), превращает их в ссылки (см. `repo::getOne` в методе `toRefList`) и сохраняет обновленную сущность `Group` (см. `return groupRepo.save(group)`).

Но в результате, помимо обязательных, я получаю лишние запросы в базу (по количесву связанных сущностей, чьи ID-шники я передаю в метод `updateGroup`) - Hibernate зачем-то загружает связанные сущности целиком, несмотря на то, что для апдейта требуются только их ID:

```sql
select group0_.id as id1_0_0_, group0_.name as name2_0_0_ from groups group0_ where group0_.id=5;

-- redundant selects:
select student0_.id as id1_2_0_, student0_.name as name2_2_0_ from students student0_ where student0_.id=3;
select student0_.id as id1_2_0_, student0_.name as name2_2_0_ from students student0_ where student0_.id=4;
--
update groups set name='g1_' where id=5;
delete from groups_students where group_id=5;
insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (5, 3);
insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (5, 4);
```

При этом во время создания сущности, которое делается аналогично, лишних запросов не возникает:

```java
public Group createGroup(String name, List<Long> studentIds) {
    List<Student> students = toRefList(studentIds, studentRepo);
    Group group = new Group(name, students);
    return groupRepo.save(group);
}
```

```sql
insert into groups (name, id) values ('g1', 5);
insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (5, 1);
insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (5, 2);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от лишних запросов? И, собственно, почему Гибернейт загружает сущности целиком, вместо того чтобы использовать их ссылки? Почему именно во время апдейта сущности?

Ссылка на [демку](https://github.com/Cepr0/m2m-redundant-queries-demo). Можно запустить в IDEA'е - все запросы будут отображаться в логе.

Comment: Hibernate имеет право проверить наличие записи в базе при вызове getReference. Может он так и поступает? Можете посмотреть когда он выполняет эти запросы: во время toRefList или groupRepo.save?

Comment: @Sergey - во время сохранения (я добавил логирование - можно глянуть...).

Comment: JPA обязывает во время сохранения устанавливать ссылки на управляемые версии сущностей, на которые ссылается сохраняемая сущность. Может быть это подразумевает в том числе и загрузку reference? Тем более, если они получены в другой транзакции. т.е. для текущей они являются detached. И вообще по спецификации "трогать" нельзя только ленивые ссылки и то, если они не были уже загружены.

Comment: В JavaDocs про `getReference` сказано, что она "Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched" и все (про ссылки только на упр. сущности там не сказано). Т.е. получает объект, чье состояние может быть лениво загружено. Др. словами, если мы захотим получить значение какого-то свойства такого объекта, Гибернейт загрузит сущность из БД. И вот почему-то Гибер это делает во время update и не делает во время insert... На счет "др. транзакции" - все происходит в одной транзации (метод `updateGroup` - транзакционный, аннотация установлена над классом сервиса). Последнюю фразу, сори, недопонял.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема решается просто, если вы уберете из вашего проекта "code smells".

Хайбернейт использует кеш, когда вытягивает сущности, и затем отслеживает их изменения. Этот кеш работает в рамках 1 транзакции. Например, чтобы изменить запись в базе, достаточно вытащить объект, вызвать геттер и завершить транзакцию. Хайбернейт автоматически уловит изменение и сделает апдейт.(не нужно вызывать дополнительных методов.) В вашем коде используется совершенно ненужный флаг

> isChanged

и

> groupRepo.save(group)

Вместо этой части кода

```
 if(isChanged) ...

 groupRepo.save(group) ...
```

сделайте следующее:

```
return groupRepo.findById(id)
                .map(group -> {
                    if (name != null) {
                        group.setName(name);
                    }
                    if (studentIds != null && !studentIds.isEmpty()) {
                        List<Student> students = toRefList(studentIds, studentRepo);
                        group.setStudents(students);
                    }
                        return group;
                });
```

И тогда вы избавитесь от лишних запросов.

Лог:

> Hibernate: select group0_.id as id1_0_0_, group0_.name as name2_0_0_ from groups group0_ where group0_.id=?
>
> Hibernate: update groups set name=? where id=?
>
> Hibernate: delete from groups_students where group_id=?
>
> Hibernate: insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (?, ?)
>
> Hibernate: insert into groups_students (group_id, students_id) values (?, ?)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Сработало )) На счет "душка" - в данном случае это не принципиально.. ) По поводу того, что Гибер отслеживает состояния сущностей и, при необходимости, сделает им самостоятельно апдейт, - я в курсе. Но вот почему явный вызов метода `save`, который, вроде бы, должен делать тоже самое, приводит к лишним запросам - не понятно... )